# Compare the length of two arrays (if then)

Tags: bash

I'm trying to compare the length of two arrays in bash, so as to determine whether to proceed with an operation.

```
if [ "${videos[@]}" -eq "${subtitles[@]}" ]; then
   i=0
   for item in ${videos[@]}
     do
        mkvmerge -o SUB_${videos[i]} ${videos[i]} --track-name "0:English" -s 0 -D -A ${subtitles[i]}
        rm ${videos[i]}
        rm ${subtitles[i]}  
    i=$((i+1))
     done
else
     echo "** Aborting! File mismatch **"
     exit
fi
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
line 11: [: too many arguments
```

Line 11 is the first line of the snippet.  Can anyone point out what mistake (or mistakes) I'm making?

Thanks!

Comment: You should also be quoting all of your parameter expansions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if [ "${#videos[@]}" -eq "${#subtitles[@]}" ]; then
        ^                   ^
```

The length of an array is `${#array[@]}` with a `#` in front.